# Is being a fanpage haram

Tags: hadith, sharia, halal-haram, halal-certification

Hello I’m 11 years old and I’m a fan of this girl and she doesn’t sing but she dances on tiktok and I’m a fan and I do take her videos and use them with text and asking people questions like if in 4 years what age will u be for example I never want to be like her at all I’m just a fan is that ok.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is ok. As long as the content is halal, and you aren't worshipping the person, it is totally fine. :)
Best,
Michelle

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Some of her content is halal I still pray and fast and also read Quran

Comment: Also she’s only 16 I don’t think she does u know the bad things like throwing it back but some vids have her doing it but there are some videos that she’s staring at the camera and I love allah and prophet Muhammad more then anyone else then I love my mother and then father

Comment: Of course! The fact that you love Allah (swt) and are making sure, shows that you care about your deen, and that is what is important! :)

Comment: Of course I love allah and prophet Muhammad more then anything on this earth

Comment: Are u sure cause I want to continue but I’m scared 

Comment: Ik but are u 100% sure cause I have my puberty but like I want to be sure cause I’m really scared 

Comment: In my opinion, it is fine. You have to remember that Allah (swt) is kind and merciful. Our religion is peace and is not meant to be stressful for you. You are committing a sin or doing anything wrong. :)

Comment: you arent worshipping them or anything.

Comment: No I don’t I’m just a fan that does videos for fun and I don’t call her “idol” I’m just a fan Allah is first

Comment: And I wanna continue and my mom said it’s fine to be a fanpage but sometimes I overthink a lot which makes me stressed and I feel in 2 ways I wanna continue but then my head says u will go to hell and I get really scared

Answer (score 0):

Just liking her itself isn’t haram

But you know, if shes on tiktok there’s probably music in her videos and thats haram. If you tell you friends (as you are her fan) you watch her videos (which have music) then youre sinning openly and that (revealing sin) too is another sin.

You may read this but plan to keep watching her. My point is, If you are adamant to sin and do it, at least do not think what you are doing is permissible. We all sin, but when we say its ok to do it, thats when we are crossing every line and denying islam.

Comment: What I do is I close my volume then I take the video and then I change the sound to one that doesn’t have bad words in it like soft like aesthetic like pouring water yh!

Comment: Ok then, i guess its fine then

Comment: Yeah so don’t worry I love allah and prophet Muhammad more! And plus my only role model is prophet Muhammad ❤️